# International flight reservation for double passport holder

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, bookings, check-in

I made a reservation with my Italian passport for a flight from the US to Germany. In the meantime, I have obtained my US passport. Can I show my Italian passport to the airline and then use the American passport for immigration, or do I have to change the reservation?
Thanks.

Comment: The only immigration officers you'll see on your outward flight will be German -- the US government does not inspect departing passengers except in rare circumstances -- and there's no reason to show them the US passport.  You'll want to show the US passport to the airline when you check in for your flight to the US and to US officers on arrival in the US, but show your Italian passport to everyone else.  You don't need to show the same passport when you check in as the one you gave when you made the reservation (except perhaps if your passports have different names).

Comment: Actually I don't think this is a duplicate as it specifically asks about different passports for  "reservation" and "travel". The answer here in most cases is that reservations are NOT tied to a specific passport: just to your name. As long as the  names are the same, you can use whatever passport you want at check in. You do NOT need to present the passport used at booking.